# What is an MLX12106J?

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

I recently acquired about 20ish components labeled MLX12106J by accident.  I have no idea what these are or what they do.  I cannot find a datasheet for this part anywhere online.  Does anyone know what this part does and/or how it functions?

Comment: Says "no longer available" - try [contacting them](https://www.melexis.com/en/search?q=MLX12106) and ask for the datasheet.  Sounds like they want it to totally disappear.

Comment: I tried.  That led to this intriguing result, "This is for a specific customer and we cannot disclose any information."  This, obviously, leads to even more questions.

Comment: The MLX12106E type is sold on Ebay and AliExpress. Maybe the seller will provide you the datasheet.

Comment: @Seir So when you order parts that are salvaged (for instance, an i8080), it is not unusual for the seller to toss in a few 7400-series chips, or 555s, or whatever.  Some of the sellers even do them up nicely as "gift packs" and some just seem to use a dime bag.  Anyway, that's how I got these. The seller doesn't seem to know, either.

Answer (score 1):

It is a sensor protection IC made by Melexis and the part is currently available. Try this link for the data sheet https://www.alldatasheet.com/view_datasheet.jsp?Searchword=MLX12106. The search term I used was: "MLX12106J PDF" and on the first page I got the information on the part a source for them and the data sheet download.

When a custom IC is manufactured it is done under a NDA (Non Disclosure Agreement) which is a legal agreement that if information is disclosed there are sever penitililes to the disclosure and others. The part is owned by the customer, not the manufacturer. Sometimes the owner retains exclusive right to the part forever, sometimes the manufacturer can make it available to its customers at some future date. Each one is different, and is generally determined at the start of the project. This is a very expensive process for all involved, where all the details are negotiated before things are signed and the part designed and manufactured. The IC probably contains IP from both the customer and manafacturer.

Comment: I think you should supply the link for that part's data sheet just to be unambiguous.

Comment: Not sure what happened I just reposted my comment, it was still in the paste buffer on my computer.  Every now and then my links get stripped out and I have to go back and look to be sure they are there. https://www.alldatasheet.com/view_datasheet.jsp?Searchword=MLX12106  Thaks Seri I had no idea to do it that way.

Comment: That's the 12101 not the 12106. You have to be very diligent with some of these dodgy websites.

Comment: Poking around and finding several 121XX parts suggest there is no commonality and I do not think it is reasonable to assume the 12101 is related to 12106 (archive.org was helpful).

As for the IP discussion yeah, but then why are these things floating around loose?  There's a lot of open questions here, hence the posting.

Comment: This link states they are in stock and shows the data sheet.  I did not generate an account to validate it. When a part number ends in xx it typically indicates there are several varieties of the part. https://www.jotrin.com/product/parts/MLX12106